# How can I do a POST request server with python?

Tags: python, http

I'm a junior programmer and I want to know how can I extract data from the query using BaseHTTPRequestHandler library in python.

I am using this code:

```
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler

class button(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
       def do_POST(self):
              pass
if __name__ == '__main__':
    from http.server import HTTPServer
    server = HTTPServer(('localhost', 4020), button)
    print('Use <Ctrl-C> to stop the server')
    server.serve_forever()
```

Can you give me some tips to solve this please?

I also found some examples where FastApi is used. Would this way
of split http message be usefull for me?

```
@app.get("/query/{query_item}")
```

Thank you, regards.

Comment: learn `flask` instead of `http.server` and then you will know how to do also in `FastAPI` because many frameworks are similar to `flask`

Comment: it seems you will have to use `content_length = int(self.headers['Content-Length'])` and `post_data = self.rfile.read(content_length)` to get data send to POST. And response should be similar to response in `GET`. But you will have to manually convert POST data and example `@app.get("/query/{query_item}")` is totally useless for you in this situation.